# Restore all applicable files in a backup device in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, t-sql, restore

I'm using SQL Server (2008 R2 in this case) and I am backing up my databases into backup devices (one per database). Every Sunday the device is overwritten with a new full backup, every night a differential backup is added and every hour a transaction log backup is added to the backup device.

When restoring this onto a new server using SSMS I first create a new database, then add the backup device and then restore from that backup device. I then have to manually select the applicable files:

- The Full backup (always the first one in the list)
- The latest differential backup
- All transaction log backups that came after the last differential backup.

[image]

This works fine for the occassional restore, but I need to automate this in T-SQL.

There is some logic on which files to pick, but I don't even know how to get to the content of the backup device yet.

I would like to have a stored procedure that takes the name of the database and the backup device and restores the latest version. Anybody knows of such a thing?

Or do I miss something here and there is a simple command for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own solution, I have just started testing it, but it looks good. All I need is the backup device file and I can go:

```
EXEC [dbo].[dba_RestoreFromBackupDevice] @DBName = 'test', @File = 'C:\test.bak', @WhatIf = 1
```

It will create the database, then read the content of the backup device and figure out which of the files to restore. Using @WhatIf it spits out sql like this:

```
USE master; 
CREATE DATABASE [lab];
RESTORE DATABASE [lab] FROM  DISK = N'C:\test.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10; 
RESTORE DATABASE [lab] FROM  DISK = N'C:\test.bak' WITH  FILE = 49, NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10;
RESTORE LOG [lab] FROM  DISK = N'C:\test.bak' WITH  FILE = 50, NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10; 
RESTORE LOG [lab] FROM  DISK = N'C:\test.bak' WITH  FILE = 51, NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10; 
RESTORE database [lab] WITH RECOVERY;
```

With @WhatIf = 0 or missing, it executes the restore process right away.

Here's the full stored procedure:

```
/* ========================================================
Author:        Peter Hahndorf
Creation date: 25-Sep-2012

Restores a database from a backup device with multiple files.
Uses the first file, the lastest differential files and
all further transactional log files.
Creates the database if not already there.
Use @WhatIf = 1 to just print the SQL statement without
executing it.
========================================================= */
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[dba_RestoreFromBackupDevice]
  @DBName varchar(100),
  @File varchar(250),
  @WhatIf bit = 0
AS
BEGIN

-- We need a table to store the backup devices file data
-- This table is for SQL Server 2008R2 earlier versions
-- have less fields, later may have more.
DECLARE @Headers TABLE (
BackupName nvarchar(128) ,
BackupDescription nvarchar(255),
BackupType smallint,
ExpirationDate datetime,
Compressed tinyint,
Position smallint,
DeviceType tinyint,
UserName nvarchar(128),
ServerName nvarchar(128),
DatabaseName nvarchar(128),
DatabaseVersion int,
DatabaseCreationDate datetime,
BackupSize numeric(20,0),
FirstLsn numeric(25,0),
LastLsn numeric(25,0),
CheckpointLsn numeric(25,0),
DifferentialBackupLsn numeric(25,0),
BackupStartDate datetime,
BackupFinishDate datetime,
SortOrder smallint,
[CodePage] smallint,
UnicodeLocaleid int,
UnicodeComparisonStyle int,
CompatibilityLevel tinyint,
SoftwareVendorId int,
SoftwareVersionMajor int,
SoftwareVersionMinor int,
SoftwareVersionBuild int,
MachineName nvarchar(128),
Flags int,
BindingId uniqueidentifier,
RecoveryForkId uniqueidentifier,
Collation nvarchar(128), 
FamilyGUID uniqueidentifier,
HasBulkLoggedData bit,
IsSnapshot bit,
IsReadOnly bit, 
IsSingleUser bit, 
HasBackupChecksums bit,
IsDamaged Int, 
BeginsLogChain bit, 
HAsIncompleteMetaData bit, 
IsForceOFfline bit, 
IsCopyOnly bit, 
FirstRecoveryForkID uniqueidentifier,
ForkPointLSN numeric(25,0),
RecoveryModel nvarchar(60),
DifferentialBaseLSN numeric(25,0),
DifferentialBAseGUID uniqueidentifier,
BackupTypeDescription nvarchar(60),
BackupSetGUID uniqueidentifier,
CompressedBackupSize bigint
);

-- this gets the content of the backup device and puts it in
-- a table so we can work with it.
INSERT @Headers EXEC ('RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK=''' + @File + '''')

/*
 The device may have one of the following combinations of files:
 Full only
 Full and at least one log
 Full, at least one diff and some further logs
 Full, at least one diff and no further logs
*/

-- We store all our commands in a string and then either print or
-- execute it at the end

DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)

SET @SQL = 'USE master; '

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = @DBName )
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + 'CREATE DATABASE [' + @DBName + ']; '
END

-- Always restore the first file, it is the only full backup in the device
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'RESTORE DATABASE [' + @DBName + '] FROM  DISK = N''' + @File + ''' WITH  FILE = 1,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10; '

-- Find the last differential backup, the highest position of any type 5 files
-- If there is none, we assign a one, which makes it the same as the full one
DECLARE @DiffFileNo INT
SELECT @DiffFileNo = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Position),1) FROM @Headers WHERE BackupType = 5)

-- If there is one, restore it
IF @DiffFileNo > 1
BEGIN       
    SET @SQL = @SQL + 'RESTORE DATABASE [' + @DBName + '] FROM  DISK = N''' + @File + ''' WITH  FILE = ' + CAST(@DiffFileNo AS VARCHAR) + ', NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10;'
END

-- now we also need all log files that are newer/greater than the last differential
DECLARE @fileno INT
DECLARE restore_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Position FROM @Headers WHERE Position > @DiffFileNo ORDER BY Position

OPEN restore_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM restore_cursor INTO @fileno
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @SQL = @SQL +  'RESTORE LOG [' + @DBName + '] FROM  DISK = N''' + @File + ''' WITH  FILE = ' + CAST(@fileno AS VARCHAR) + ', NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10; '

FETCH NEXT FROM restore_cursor INTO @fileno
END
CLOSE restore_cursor
DEALLOCATE restore_cursor

-- finally we have to finish the restore
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'RESTORE database [' + @DBName + '] WITH RECOVERY; '

IF @WhatIf = 1
BEGIN
    PRINT @SQL
END 
ELSE
BEGIN
    EXEC(@SQL)
END

END
```

Answer (score 3):

This procedure should do what you want:

```
create procedure dbo.dbrestore
@dbname nvarchar(50)
as
declare @fileno integer
declare @dumpdevice nvarchar(50)
declare @mediasetid integer
declare @position integer

select top(1) @dumpdevice=a.logical_device_name, @mediasetid=b.media_set_id, @position=b.position from backupmediafamily a inner join backupset b on a.media_set_id=b.media_set_id
where b.database_name='backuptest' and b.type='D' order by a.media_set_id desc, b. position desc

declare restore_cursor cursor for
select position from msdb.dbo.backupset where database_name=@dbname and type='D' and media_set_id=@mediasetid and position=@position
union
select  max(position) as position from msdb.dbo.backupset where database_name=@dbname and type='I' and media_set_id=@mediasetid and position>@position
union
select position from msdb.dbo.backupset where database_name=@dbname and type='L' and media_set_id=@mediasetid and position>@position
and last_lsn>(select max(last_lsn)from msdb.dbo.backupset where database_name=@dbname and type='I' and media_set_id=@mediasetid and position>@position)
order by position asc;

open restore_cursor
fetch next from restore_cursor into @fileno
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
--comment the print statement and uncomment the exec statement to run
--exec('restore database ['+@dbname+'] from '+@dumpdevice+' with norecovery, replace, FILE='+@fileno+';')
  print ('restore database ['+@dbname+'] from '+@dumpdevice+' with norecovery, replace, FILE='+convert(varchar(4),@fileno)+';')
fetch next from restore_cursor into @fileno
end
close restore_cursor
deallocate restore_cursor
--exec('restore database ['+@dbname+'] with recovery;')
go
```

execution goes:

get the name of the dumpdevice based on the supplied database name. I'm assuming that they are all on the same device. The top is to work around having multiple media sets per database if using 'with format' for the initial DB, and to cope with the possibility of multiple full backups in the device

Then build up a union query consisting of:

The last full database backup (type=D) in the device

the last differential backup (type=I and has the greatest LSN (Log Sequence Number)) taken after the last full db backup.

the transaction logs (type=L) taken after the above diff.

returning just the position value, which maps to the FILE value in this case (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186299.aspx)

Loop through the result restoring them individually, and then a final restore with recovery to finish it off.

Call it as:

```
exec dbrestore 'db2restore'
```

I've tried it on a test db and it appears to work happily, and comparing it to the files SSMS wants to restore for the same operation it looks the same.

Provided as is, there's probably typos, I've probably missed a possible boundary condition, and there's no error checking.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, this was helpful in some ways, but it just works for backup devices that were created on the same server. It uses information about the devices from system tables, which it seems get in there when the backup is running on the same server. Adding a device to the server, still doesn't put the information about the files into the msdb tables. Because the restore happens on a different server I had to read the content of the device from the device itself (see my answer). Thanks anyway.